# MSBuild - how can i specify the output file path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am building my cpp app using MSBuild. I am using the following command:

```
MSBuild <path_to_sln> /t:ProjectName:rebuild /p:OutDir=C:\projOutput\;configuration=release
```

`lib`, `pdb` and `exp` files are put in the `projOutput` folder, however the exe is not there. I can see in the log that the exe is put into another directory.

How can i set and force the directory in which the exe will be placed?

Comment: Which folder the exe is going into instead of the output folder you are setting?

Comment: Do you have any post-build steps in your project that might be moving the .exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you show is correct. You can verify this by creating a new project: without modifying any settings pdb and exe go in OutDir. If this doesn't work for you, the only possibility seems the project is overriding the exe path somewhere. Look in the project settings, or if it's a custom project check the `TargetName` property.